# EOF function won't work

Tags: vb.net, eof

I'm just trying to get a simple practice eof function to work but it's not working I was just wondering if anybody knew a quick reason as to why. Here is the simple function:

```
Public Sub endOF()
    Dim textline As String
    FileOpen(1, "TESTFILE", OpenMode.Input)     'Open file
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        textline = LineInput(1)
        Debug.WriteLine(textline)

    Loop
    FileClose(1)
End Sub
```

The error happens at `EOF(1)`

Comment: Does the file "TESTFILE" exist? Since you ripped this from msdn? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ct2yy4s(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I would very much recommend against using the VB.NET functions that take a file handle number as a parameter, and instead use the more general .NET framework methods that use streams. Try this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10382868/edit

Comment: do we need to guess at the error?

Comment: Definitely use IO namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably put `testfile.txt` in the wrong folder, try putting it in folder `C:\`

and edit your method. Be sure to write some text in your testfile.

```
Public Sub endOF()
    Dim textline As String
    FileOpen(1, "C:\TESTFILE.TXT", OpenMode.Input)     'Open file
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        textline = LineInput(1)
        Debug.WriteLine(textline)

    Loop
    FileClose(1)
End Sub
```